# JSON Object to string with PHP / JavaScript

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have below JSON object, that is being posted from my frontend to my backend with Axios:

```
 this.columns = JSON.parse(this.columns);
```

This can look like:

```
columns: {
    1: {
        position: "10"
    },
    2: {
        position: "35"
    },
    3: {
        position: "20"
    }
}
```

Now, I need to sort this JSON object on my backend from lowest to highest `position` **and** then convert the JSON object to a string (because I am using the values in another command line input):

```
"{\"1\":{\"position\":\"10\"},\"2\":{\"position\":\"20\"},\"3\":{\"position\":\"35.00\"}}"
```

I am trying to sort this and then convert it to a string with PHP:

```php
//Sort the columns
sort($this->columns);
$columns = json_encode($this->columns);
```

But this returns the columns as an array:

```
"[{"position":"10"},{"position":"20"},{"position":"35"}]"
```

How can I sort the JSON object, but return it as a string so I can use it on the command line?

Comment: It really really help sif you examples are consistent!!!!! Where did `45.15` come from ? Or is that part of your problem?? Numbers that just appear out of knowhere

Comment: HINT: Convert the JSON String to a PHP Data Typ `json_decode()` and then sort the resulting array

Comment: JSON String example is not valid JSON ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think This is What You Need

### First Variant:

```
json_encode($this->columns, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

### Second Variant

```
json_encode((object) $this->columns);
```

This gives you Json Object String
Example:

```
{"0":{"position":"10"},"1":{"position":"20"},"2":{"position":"35"}}
```

Consider Upvote if this answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with true flag and use [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php),

```
$temp = json_decode($temp['columns'], true);
array_multisort(array_column($temp['columns'], "position"), SORT_ASC, $temp['columns']);
echo json_encode($temp['columns']);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/tB2UR).

**Output:-**

```
[{"position":"10"},{"position":"20"},{"position":"35"}]
```

Comment: Great, except you invented an array as input when the OP suggests they have an **JSON String** representing an impossible json object structure ???

Comment: No what I mean is this does not address the reality of the question and as such in no use to the OP